# FileStream read file time out

Tags: vb.net, filestream

I am using this code to read a Windows spooler file on vb.net:

```vb
Dim SpoolFileStream As New FileStream(SpoolFilename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read)

'\\ Open a binary reader for the spool file using above encoding
Dim SpoolBinaryReader As New BinaryReader(SpoolFileStream, Encoding.GetEncoding(857))
```

The filestream is always giving a read timeout error